# Can't remove border from Angular2-wizard form stepper rendered html

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm using [angular2-wizard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-wizard) to create form wizards on my page. The way you add the wizard is with this custom element

```
<form-wizard>
```

and when it renders you have children that look like this
[image]

**Stackblitz** - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-narv3q?file=app/app.component.css)

**Problem** - I want to remove the border around the "card" class that is the first div inside the 'form-wizard'. But I'm not having any luck with what I've tried.

Border shown here
[image]

Here is what I've tried

```js
styles: [
  `
    :host >>> form-wizard + div {
      border: none !important;
    }
    :host >>> form-wizard + div.card {
      border: none !important;
    }
    :host >>> form-wizard+div.card {
      border: none !important;
    }
    :host >>> form-wizard+div .card {
      border: none !important;
    }
    
    `
]
```

```css
In my .CSS file

:host ::ng-deep form-wizard+div {
  border: none !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep form-wizard+div.card {
  border: none !important;
}

In styles inside component
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

```
:host ::ng-deep form-wizard > div.card:first-child
```

Answer (score 1):

well i think you should add tow lines of css one for removing the border and one to undo that for the rest of the .card class elements like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-9wlohh?file=app/app.component.css)

please check it

```
 ::ng-deep form-wizard > div.card {
  border: none; 
}

::ng-deep form-wizard > .card ~ .card {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

also another thing that comes in mined is to do it like this

```
::ng-deep form-wizard  div.card  {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
 ::ng-deep form-wizard > div.card {
  border: none; 
}
```

but here you need to make sure the order of the statement is like this, so styles does not get overwriten because of the css specificity

Comment: Hi Moneer. What does the second statement do? Is it to test?

Comment: yes here it is only for test, yes my idea is that one statement will apply border to all and the other will remove it for the first element

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fairly simple and the only thing is what you have done has the wrong selector used.

Firstly, here's the solution for the asked problem [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-krqcrz?file=app/app.component.css) :

```
::ng-deep form-wizard > .card {
  border: none;
}

// if you want to remove the border of card which is inside the selected stepper
::ng-deep form-wizard wizard-step .card {
  border: none;
}
```

---

Now I want to share few things, there are multiple ways (preferences) of selecting an element for styling, especially I want to put a focus on 3 selectors as they are relevant here to understand the solution.

```
element1 > element2 
// Selects all <element2> where the parent is an <element1>
// Ex: div > p 
// Selects all the <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element
```

Below is the live example you may want to take a look at.

```css
div > p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> Paragraph 1: I am a direct child of div.</p>
  <section>
    <p> Paragraph 2: I am not a direct child of div.</p>  
    <p> Paragraph 3: I am not a direct child of div.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

```
element1 + element2 
// Selects the first <element2> that is placed immediately after <element1> 
// Ex: div + p 
// Selects the first <p> element that is placed immediately after <div> element
```

Below is the live example you may want to take a look at.

```css
div + p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Div 1: I am a div element.</div>
<p>Paragraph 1: I am the first <p> sibling of div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2: I am the second <p> sibling of div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 3: I am the third <p> sibling of div.</p>
```

```
element1 ~ element2 
// Selects every <element1> that is preceded by an <element2>
// Ex: div ~ p 
// Selects every <p> element that is preceded by a <div> element
```

Below is the live example you may want to take a look at.

```css
div ~ p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Div 1: I am a div element.</div>
<p>Paragraph 1: I am the first <p> sibling of div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2: I am the second <p> sibling of div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 3: I am the third <p> sibling of div.</p>
```

Hope it may help you understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a bit more easily by removing the encapsulation in your angular file so the styles work without having to specify them so much.
[Proposed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INIOx.png) [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-eunwbp)

Answer (score 0):

`::ng-deep` is depreciated.[check here.](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

One way you can do this is by adding the desired styles to application styles.css files and they will work. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-jsl4dd?file=styles.css)

**styles.css**

```
form-wizard > .card {
  border: none;
}
```